# Parallels Desktop и macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, виртуальная-машина

Установила macOS Big Sure. Бэклог не делала. Включаю Parallels Desktop и получаю сообщение "Для завершения установки Parallels Desktop перезапустите Mac".
После 27 перезапуска сообщение повторяется.
Очень не хочется сносить систему, а Parallels Desktop очень нужна.
Как оживить VM?

Comment: А вы пробовали писать в поддержку Parallels?

Comment: а как? не найду инфу

Comment: Когда же уже люди поймут, что для macOS нужен Mac...

Comment: @ЛадаПенькова на официальном сайте есть раздел поддержки